# Extract single word using grep

Tags: bash, shell

I have following types of strigs. Each of them are part of a large string.

1. `...... UUID: a062832a; UID: Z6IxbK9; UUID: null; ......`
2. `...... UUID: a062832a; UID: Z6IxbK9; ......`
3. `...... UID: Z6IxbK9; UUID: null; ......`

I want to extract the value associated with UID, i.e `Z6IxbK9`. Right now Im using following expression to extract it.

```
value=`echo $line | grep -o '\<UID.*\>' | awk -F\; '{ print $1 }' | cut -d: -f2 | tr -d ' '`
```

I feel this not the efficient way of doing this. I'm invoing four different commands which is slowing down the processing of a big file.

Can anyone suggest a better solution.

Comment: You should be able to do it all in `awk`. It can process regular expressions using `sub()`, and it can split strings using `split()`.

Comment: Thanks Barmar. Do you have any suggesion where I can check more about sub and split().

Comment: They're described in the `awk` man page.

Answer (score 2):

Play with non greedy match `.*?` together with `-P` (perl regexp), eg. try this:

```
 grep -P -o ' UID:.*?;' file | sed 's/ UID: //;s/;//'
```

Result:

```
$ echo '...stuff stuff... UUID: a062832a; UID: ABCZ6IxbK9; UUID: null; ......
    ..foo bar.... UUID: a062832a; UID: DEFZ6IxbK9; ......
    .. hello.... UID: ghiZ6IxbK9; UUID: null; ......
' | grep -P -o ' UID:.*?;' | sed 's/ UID: //;s/;//'

ABCZ6IxbK9
DEFZ6IxbK9
ghiZ6IxbK9
```

Comment: Thanks jimmij, your solution atleast gave me the UID: xxxx. Now I can remove awk. Do you have any doc or links explaining usage of ? in grep

Comment: @Abhijeet Normally GNU grep doesn't allow non greedy matching, thus `-P` option which tells to use perl regexp. You can read about it in many places on the web. BTW, I added sed in pipe to my answer to match only string after UID.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `awk`:

```
string="...... UUID: a062832a; UID: Z6IxbK9; UUID: null; ......
...... UUID: a062832a; UID: Z6IxbK9; ......
...... UID: Z6IxbK9; UUID: null; ......"

awk '
{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
        if($i == "UID:") { 
            s=$(i+1)
            sub(";","",s)
            print s
        }
}' <<<"$string"
```

Output:

```
Z6IxbK9
Z6IxbK9
Z6IxbK9
```

Answer (score 0):

This "`awk`-`sed`" combo:

`awk -F' UID:' '{print $2}' file | sed 's/;.*//'`

gives:

```
 Z6IxbK9
 Z6IxbK9
 Z6IxbK9
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this simply through a single grep command which uses `-P`(*Perl-regex*) parameter.

```
$ grep -oP '\bUID:\s*\K[^;]*' file
Z6IxbK9
Z6IxbK9
Z6IxbK9
```

**Explanation:**

- `\b` Word boundary which matches between a word character and a non-word character.
- `UID:\s*` Matches the string `UID:` along with the spaces following.
- `\K` This would discards the previously matched characters in our case it's `UID:<space>`.
- `[^;]*` Now it matches any character not of `;` zero or more times.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just `sed -n $'s/^.*[^U]UID:[\040\t]*\\([^;]*\\).*$/\\1/p'`?

Answer (score 0):

`grep` with look-behind:

```
$ cat file
...... UUID: a062832a; UID: Z6IxbK9; UUID: null; ......
...... UUID: a062832a; UID: Z6IxbK9; ......
...... UID: Z6IxbK9; UUID: null; ......

$ grep -oP '(?<=\bUID: )[^;]*' file
Z6IxbK9
Z6IxbK9
Z6IxbK9
```

Explanation:

```
\bUID - UID, preceded by white-space.
(?<=\bUID) - Any text preceded by \bUID
[^;]* - anything till (& not including) a ';'
```

Comment: Note: Logically this is similar to @AvinashRaj's answer, but the syntax is different.